# Neural Network Training - Multiple Output CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN to play a game similar to myself. The pixel input should be mapped to an output which is whether or not to press:

- q
- w
- e
- r
- d
- f
- right click
- left click
- hover the mouse over a certain pixel location

or a combination of any of the above simultaneously, sometimes holding down some buttons while pressing others.

What is the best way to go about capturing this training data, I am mostly concerned with what the output vector might look like that I am mapping the pixel input to.

Any advice is really appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to relate to both "Reinforcement learning" and CNNs.

This question is very broad.

I can suggest looking at the following example  for [Tutorial of playing Doom](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-deep-q-learning-lets-play-doom-54d02d8017d8) given only an input of raw pixels to get yourself started.